# How to make my dots match my boxplot in basic r plot?

Tags: r

I am plotting a boxplot and a line showing two different variables with a common x axis but I can´t make them align on the same point in the x axis. So the dots of the line are off from the centre of the boxplot. Is there a way to fix this? This is my code and the plot as I got it.[image]

```
    ##Plotting variation total VOC vs temperatura per month
par(mar=c(2, 5, 1, 4))
boxplot(data=general_voc, daily_voc~Month, 
        xlab='', ylab='',
        col=color_pal[1],
        bg=color_pal[1],
        type = 'l',
        main='',cex=0.1,yaxt='n',
        ann = FALSE)
axis(2, ylim=c(0,max(general_voc$daily_voc,na.rm = T)),
     col='black',lwd=0.2,cex = 0.8,las=1)
mtext(2,text='Total BVOC (ppb)',line=2.5,
      col="black",cex = 1.2,las=0)
par(new=T) #START A NEW PLOT OVER THE DAME FRAME
plot.default(mean_temp$Month,mean_temp$temp,#plot temperature
     xlab='', ylab='',
     col=color_pal[2],
     bg=color_pal[2],
     type = 'b',
     main='',cex=0.8,yaxt='n',
     xaxt='n')
axis(4, ylim=c(0,max(mean_temp$temp,na.rm = T)),#Second axis set up
     col=color_pal[2],
     col.axis = color_pal[2],
     lwd=0.2,
     cex = 0.8,
     las=1)
mtext(4,text='avg T (°C)',line=2.5,#Add the label second y axis
      col = color_pal[2],
      cex = 1.2,las=0)
```

Edit: Adding a new plot with the observed offset between both plots and sample of the data. 
avg_temp:

```
  month  temp
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2  22.4
2     3  20.6
3     4  18.3
4     5  15.0
5     6  11.8
```

general_voc:

```
    day month daily_voc avg_temp avg_voc Month
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>
1     1     3    19.2       23.2  1.20   Mar  
2     1     5    11.9       17.9  0.853  May  
3     1     6     0.247     13.8  0.0145 Jun  
4     2     3    15.7       23.2  1.30   Mar  
5     2     4     0         19.8  0      Apr  
6     2     5    13.6       19.7  0.905  May
```

Comment: Hi Jhonathan, it would be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(general_voc)` and `dput(mean_temp)`. You can edit the post with the output. However, I have two thoughts. 1) Your boxplot has a factor on the x axis, but your line plot has `mean_temp$Month`, which may or may not be a factor. 2) You could try controlling the x axis limits with `xlim = c(0,4)`.

Comment: Thanks Ian. Indeed the X axis is a factor. Though that was the easiest way to plot the boxplot. I´ll try playing with that and the x lim. Cheers

Comment: So I tried changing from factor to numeric and adding the xlim. still the same result. To see what was happening I let both x-axis in the plot and it's showing an offset. Any ideas on how to fix it? See new plot on the post. Also I included a sample of both dfs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `plot.default`, you can use `points` to get your dots aligned with x axis of your boxplot.

Here, I generate fake dataframe mimicking your boxplot and your dots. I also set the same factor order for x axis for each dataframe:

```r
general_voc <- data.frame(Month = sample(c("Feb","Mar","May","Jun"),100,replace = TRUE),
                         daily_voc = sample(0:100,100,replace = TRUE))
general_voc$Month <- factor(general_voc$Month, levels = c("Feb","Mar","May","Jun"))

mean_temp <- data.frame(Month = c("Feb","Mar","May","Jun"),
                        temp = c(22,20,15,11))
mean_temp$Month <- factor(mean_temp$Month, levels = c("Feb","Mar","May","Jun"))
```

To plot two dataframe with a different range of values, you will need to scale up values for your dots in order to match the same range of values used for boxplot:

```r
mean_temp$temp2 <- mean_temp$temp * max(general_voc$daily_voc)/max(mean_temp$temp)
```

Then, you can plot this new points but for the annotations of the second Y axis of your graph, use `at` and `labels` arguments to place appropriate values:

```r
par(mar=c(2, 5, 1, 4))
boxplot(data=general_voc, daily_voc~Month, 
        xlab='', ylab='',
        col="green",
        #bg=color_pal[1],
        type = 'l',
        main='',cex=0.1,yaxt='n',
        ann = FALSE)
axis(2, ylim=c(0,max(general_voc$daily_voc,na.rm = T)),
     col='black',lwd=0.2,cex = 0.8,las=1)
mtext(2,text='Total BVOC (ppb)',line=2.5,
      col="black",cex = 1.2,las=0)

points(x = mean_temp$Month, y = mean_temp$temp2, col = "blue", type = "b")
axis(4, ylim=c(0,max(mean_temp$temp2,na.rm = T)),#Second axis set up
     col="blue",
     col.axis = "blue",
     lwd=0.2,
     cex = 0.8,
     las=1, 
     at = seq(0,max(mean_temp$temp2),length.out = 5),
     labels = seq(0,max(mean_temp$temp),length.out = 5))
mtext(4,text='avg T (°C)',line=2.5,#Add the label second y axis
      col = "blue",
      cex = 1.2,las=0)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Well, this will work if both df uses the same Y axis but that is not the case. I tried a similar approach with lines. Both of those functions keep the same Y axis from the box plot.

Comment: I edtied my answer to show you how to set a dual y axis plot. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Boxplots assume the group variable is a factor, so the x-axis ticks are seq(1, n) where n is the number of levels of the factor. Your general_voc data has only 4 levels for Month, and these are placed at x-axis positions 1, 2, 3, and 4. Your second plot is using month on the x-axis, a numeric variable, and the unique values are 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. Starting a new plot with par(new=TRUE) is then going to ignore the previous axes values.

The solution is to put everything in the same data frame, use `points()` to plot the second plot, but use month as a factor so the values align with the previous boxplot.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- full_join(general_voc, mean_temp, by="month")

par(mar=c(2, 5, 1, 4))
boxplot(data=data, daily_voc~month, na.action="na.pass",
        xlab='', ylab='', 
        ylim=c(0,25),
        type = 'l',
        main='',cex=0.1,yaxt='n',
        ann = FALSE, xaxt='n')
axis(side=1, at=1:5, labels=month.abb[sort(unique(data$month))])
axis(2, ylim=c(0,max(general_voc$daily_voc,na.rm = T)),
     col='black',lwd=0.2,cex = 0.8,las=1)
mtext(2,text='Total BVOC (ppb)', line=2.5,
      col="black",cex = 1.2,las=0)

points(data=data, temp~factor(month), 
             xlab='', ylab='', 
             type = 'p',
             main='',cex=0.8, yaxt='n',
             xaxt='n')
```

[image]

---

**Data**:

```
general_voc <- structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), month = c(3L, 
5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L), daily_voc = c(19.2, 11.9, 0.247, 15.7, 0, 
13.6), avg_temp = c(23.2, 17.9, 13.8, 23.2, 19.8, 19.7), avg_voc = c(1.2, 
0.853, 0.0145, 1.3, 0, 0.905), Month = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Apr", "Jun", "Mar", "May"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

mean_temp <- structure(list(month = 2:6, temp = c(22.4, 20.6, 18.3, 15, 11.8
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
))
```